# How do I write a PHP loop to display data from a database query in Table format?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

**Array Output**

```
print_r($hours_effort_result); //prints below output

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [RESOURCE_ID] => 1
                [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 1
                [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
                [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 120
                [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [RESOURCE_ID] => 2
                [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 2
                [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
                [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 140
                [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
            )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
            [RESOURCE_ID] => 3
            [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 1
            [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 170
            [MONTH_YEAR] => AUG-2015
            )   

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [RESOURCE_ID] => 4
                    [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 2
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180
                    [MONTH_YEAR] => AUG-2015
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

)

foreach ($hours_effort_result as $hours_effort_data){

        echo '<pre>';print_r($hours_effort_data);//below output
}

Array
(
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RESOURCE_ID] => 1
            [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 1
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 120
            [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [RESOURCE_ID] => 2
            [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 2
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 140
            [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RESOURCE_ID] => 3
            [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 1
            [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 170
            [MONTH_YEAR] => AUG-2015
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [RESOURCE_ID] => 4
            [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 2
            [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 180
            [MONTH_YEAR] => AUG-2015
        )
)

Array
(
)
```

**Display Months and Site**

```
print_R($project_months); //outputs below data

Array
(
    [0] => JUN-2015
    [1] => JUL-2015
    [2] => AUG-2015
    [3] => SEP-2015
)


echo '<tr>';

        foreach($project_months as $month_year){

            echo '<td>Site</strong></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$month_year.'</td>';
        }
echo '</tr>';
```

**Desired Output**

```
Name of Engineer    Site  Jun-15  Site   Jul-15  Site     Aug-15  Site  Sep-15  
User 1                            Onsite  120    Offshore  170              
User 2                            Onsite  140    Offshore  180
```

As one can see, Month `Jun` and `Sep` do not contain any data and so the array is empty while other months contains data which are printed in tabular format.  The only data to be printed are `Engineer Name, Site and Hours`

How do I loop the array in order to achieve above output?

Comment: Can you `print_r($hours_effort_result);`?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy put how you set $hours_effort_result into a while loop, then inside do the data displaying.  I'd write an example if you included how you set the array to equal something..

Comment: and why is the downvote ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I suspect not enough information, or it's already been asked on this site.

Comment: You want your thead dynamically add data?

Comment: @Codepenisbetter, would be great if you post similar question link or you want more information. provided the output of both arrays and how do I need to display it in tabular form looping the data.

Comment: @aldrin27, yes you got it right. Loop the array in such a way to display data in desired tabular format.

Comment: You don't have `JUN` and `SEP` in your array. So it can't display it that way. You can only add dynamic in your tabular if there's a data in your array

Comment: Correct, we can skip the empty data, but how do I dynamically print the existing data for `Jul` and `Aug`. Please see my updated question on how months are being displayed.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy it looked like you were asking about looping data out of a database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming you have this variable defined:

```
$project_months = Array('JUN-2015', 'JUL-2015', 'AUG-2015', 'SEP-2015' );
```

First, create an array of users:

```
<?php 

$user_array = Array();

foreach ( $project_months as $month ) 
{
    foreach ($hours_effort_result as $key => $data)
    {
        if ( ! empty ($data) )
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $val )
            {
                if ( $val['MONTH_YEAR'] == $month ) 
                {
                  $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['SITE_STATUS'] = $val['SITE_STATUS'];
                  $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['ACTUAL_HOURS'] = $val['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Second, in the table, loop through the `$user_array` and add `n/a` to those months without data.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>Jun-15</th>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>Jul-15</th>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>Aug-15</th>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>Sep-15</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($user_array as $user_name => $user_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print ($user_name); ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($project_months as $month): ?>
            <?php if ( array_key_exists( $month, $user_data ) ): ?>
                <td><?php print ($user_data[$month]['SITE_STATUS']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print ($user_data[$month]['ACTUAL_HOURS']); ?></td>
            <?php else: ?>
                <td>n/a</td>
                <td>n/a</td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to foreach the `$data` again because it is nested array.

Comment: @aldrin27, was about to post the same. Can not directly access `$data`

Comment: Something like this `foreach ($hours_effort_result as $key => $data) {
  foreach ($data as $index => $val) {
  $project_months[$index][$key] = $val;
 }
}`

Comment: Right, missed that. Actually, if your table rows are grouped by username, it's better maybe just to recreate an array containing data per user.

Comment: Could you please post a snippet about the same

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I've completely rewritten my answer, please check. This should work for your particular case, but maybe more automation is needed in practice.

Comment: @JohnDoe He wants the head also dynamic

Comment: @aldrin27 with `$project_months` defined already, the `thead` can be pretty dynamic if he wants...

Comment: @JohnDoe, creating user_array and looping through it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a **breakline** into this code.

```
$table = '';
    $table .= '<table>';
    $table .= '<thead>';
    $table .= '<th>Name of Engineer</th>';
    $table .= '<th>Site</th>';

    foreach ($arr as $key => $data)
    {
        foreach($data as $key2 => $val)
        {
            if ( ! empty($val) )
            {

                $table .= '<th>' . $val['MONTH_YEAR'] . '</th>';
            }
            else
            {
                $table .= '</th>';

            }
        }

    }
    $table .= '<br>';
    $table .= '</thead>';
    $table .= '<tbody>';

    foreach ($arr as $key => $data)
    {
        foreach($data as $key2 => $val)
        {
            if ( ! empty($val) )
            {
                $table .= '<td>'.$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME'].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td>'. $val['SITE_STATUS'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>'. $val['ACTUAL_HOURS'] .'</td>';


            }
            else
            {
                $table .= '<td></td>';
                $table .= '<td></td>';

            }

        }


    }


    $table .= '</tbody>';
    $table .= '</table>';
    echo $table;
```

Comment: The output prints same months multiple times in `<th>`. Do I need to change the formatting ?

Comment: Can i see the output?

Comment: Example output `Name of Engineer Site JUL-2015 JUL-2015 JUL-2015 JUL-2015
User 1       Onsite 40         User 2      Onsite     140`

Comment: Mine's output is `Name of Engineer Site JUL-2015 JUL-2015 AUG-2015 AUG-2015
User 1 Onsite 120 User 2 Onsite 140 User 1 Offshore 170 User 2 Offshore 180`

Comment: Yes, but you see that month names are repeated and engineer name displayed in one single line